# Freetextbox for WinForms

Tags: html, winforms

I would like to provide a textbox in a client WinForms application for setting up the body text of an email and I know there's the excellent Freetextbox for asp.net, but is there anything like it for Winforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one: https://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/RicherTextBox.aspx